Finding a general solution to $\int{\frac{dx}{x^2 + px + q}}$
I'm trying to find a general solution to $$\int{\frac{dx}{x^2 + px + q}}$$
It is given that $4q > p^2$
I was given a useful hint to transform the integral into the form $$C_1 \int{\frac{du}{u^2 + 1}},$$ but I have absolutely no idea how to find a proper $u$.
I got as far as $$\int{\frac{dx}{\require{cancel} (x^\cancel{2} + \frac{p}{2})^2 - \frac{1}{4}p^2 + q}}$$ and I don't know how to proceed. I tried to equate the denominator of the above expression with $u^2 + 1$ and solve for $u$, but that obviously didn't work and just made things more complicated given the $du$.
On integral-calculator.com they substituted $u = \frac{2x+p}{2\sqrt{q-\frac{p^2}{4}}}$ to get $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{q-\frac{p^2}{4}}}\int{\frac{du}{u^2 + 1}} $$
The problem is, I cannot figure out how this $u$ value was found. Without a proper algorithmic approach to finding this $u$, I would be unable to evaluate the integral. Does this just have to be memorized (irrespective of by rote or through practice)?
Edit: removed the exponent on $x$ at the third expression.

If it has two real roots you can use the method of partial fractions.

@Akiva Weinberger The assumption is that it doesn't, since we don't know what $p$ and $q$ are.

@BarackBarackBarack are you looking for closed form for specific p,q

@whatamidoing I'm looking for a general expression that simplifies the integral for any $p,q$ where $4q > p^2$.

It is uncommon for a single substitution to make everything immediate. In this case, first substitution is, say, $v = x + \frac{p}{2}$  to reach $\frac{1}{v^2 +  \Delta}$ with $\Delta > 0$   so we may name $\delta = \sqrt \Delta $  and make a second substitution... So, what does one do with $\frac{1}{v^2 + \delta^2}  dv  ; ? ; ; ; $

You made a small mistake when completing the square. Your expression will have $x^4$. Instead, it is $x^2 + px + q = (x+p/2)^2 - p^2/4 + q$ then factoring out $-p^2/4+q$ yields the expression
$$ (-p^2/4+q) \left( \, \left( \frac{x + p/2}{\sqrt{-p^2/4+q}} \right)^2 + 1 \, \right) $$
This substitution will not have any issues.

I don't follow. I'm not sure what you mean by "factoring out" $-\frac{p^2}{4} + q$, since at that stage $p$ and $q$ are still different terms separate of $x$ in the denominator. I think you skipped an intermediary step that I would benefit from seeing. (Also, my completion of the square was correct, I just made a copy error when I was typing the question)

@BarackBarackBarack $p$ and $q$ are both real numbers, so $-p^2/4+q$ is also a real number. you could assign an intermediate parameter like $r = -p^2/4+q$. Then, the expression becomes $(x+p/2)^2 + r$. What I mean by "factoring out" is reversing distribution, so this becomes $r,( (x+p/2)^2/r + 1 )$ which you can verify by distributing the $r$.
Also, I also made a typo in my original post that I fixed.

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{ax^2+bx+c}$$

$$I=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{2}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2ax+b}{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}\right) & \Delta< 0 \\
      \frac{-2}{2ax+b} & \Delta= 0 \\
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\ln\left(\frac{2ax+b-\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2ax+b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}\right) & \Delta> 0 
   \end{cases}$$

For our case we have, $a=1,b=p,c=q$

$$I=\begin{cases} 
      \color{red}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{4q-p^2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{2x+p}{\sqrt{4q-p^2}}\right)} & \color{red}{p^2<4q} \\
      \frac{-2}{2x+p} & p^2=4q \\
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2-4q}}\ln\left(\frac{2x+p-\sqrt{p^2-4q}}{2x+p+\sqrt{p^2-4q}}\right) & p^2>4q 
   \end{cases}$$

How?
$$\frac{1}{ax^2+bx+c}=\frac{1}{a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}}$$
$$I=\int\frac{1}{a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}}\,dx$$
$$I=\frac1a\int\frac{1}{\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{4ac-b^2}}{2a}\right)^2}\,dx$$
Now you can utilize the above conditions and solve these integrals by comparing against standard integrals, however I am not fully sure about the restrictions on $a,b,c$
For instance my answer fails for $a=c=0,b=1$ and $a=1,b=c=0$ and so on
Note : $\Delta$ here represents $b^2-4ac$ or the discriminant
